# Compare Files and print difference using print unless

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

i got the following function and dont know how to put the output into a variable.

```
sub checkFiles {
# Declaration
my $origDir="/home/hbo/test/chksum/";
my $tmpDir="/home/hbo/test/tmp/";

# get directory inventory
opendir( DIR, $origDir);
my @files = sort ( grep { !/^\.|\.\.}$/ } readdir(DIR) );
closedir(DIR);
foreach my $file (@files) {
  if ( !-r $origDir.$file) { print $origDir.$file, "does not exist"; next;}

  # open filehandles
  open my $a_fh, '<', $origDir.$file or die "$origDir.$file: $!";
  open my $b_fh, '<', $tmpDir.$file or die "$tmpDir.$file: $!";

  # map difference
  my %tmpDirFile;
  @tmpDirFile{map { unpack 'A*', $_ } <$b_fh>} = ();

  # print difference
  while (<$a_fh>) {
    print unless exists $tmpDirFile{unpack 'A*', $_};
  }
  close $a_fh;
  close $b_fh;
  }
}
```

The Line i got the questions is "print unless exists $tmpDirFile{unpack 'A*', $_};" i want to put this output into a variable like an array where i can decide between "changed" or "deleted" or "new". A short summary what my script will do: it builds a md5 sum of a directory, check if the directory differs from the version before and print the differences with flags like "new", "deleted", "changed". And yes I don't want to use additional libraries.

The output on console is:

```
40567504a8a2f9f665695a49035b381b /home/hbo/test/somedir/some/some.conf
```

Now I want to show if the file has changed, deleted or is new. Because of this i need to put the output into a variable. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash to do that. It's a bit like counting, just that you don't simply count, but keep a list of files in each key. It would look like this:

```
{
    new => [
        'file1',
        'file3',
    ],
    deleted => [
        'file4',
    ],
    changed => ]
        'file5',
    ],
},
```

Create that hash (or in my example a hash reference) outside the loop, and then push into the array ref in the appropriate key. You don't even need to create the array ref, *autovivification* will take care of that for you.

```
my $diff; # we keep track here
foreach my $file (@files) {

# ...

while (my $line = <$a_fh>) {
        if ( exists $tmpDirFile{unpack 'A*', $line} ) {
            # do stuff to check what the difference is 
            if ( find_diff($line) ){
                push @{ $diff->{changed} }, $line;
            } else {
                push @{ $diff->{deleted} }, $line;
            }
        } else {
             push @{ $diff->{new} }, $line;
        }
    }
}
```